# modal Bootstrap se ejecuta en pantalla completa con Angular

Tags: bootstrap, angular, modal

cuando pulso el botón para ver  mi modal, este se ejecuta a pantalla completa .

**api-login.component.html**

```
<ng-template #modLogin let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Hello, World!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(modLogin)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

**api-login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-login',
  templateUrl: './api-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbModalConfig, NgbModal]
})

export class ApiLoginComponent implements OnInit {
 usuario: String="";
 clave: String="";
 nameMod: String="";
url: string; 
    constructor(config: NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal){ //Variables de modal
      config.backdrop = 'static'; //Modal
      config.keyboard = false;//Modal
      this.url="/angular/php/login.php"
     // this.login();
     this.modalService.open(this.nameMod);
    }

ngOnInit() {} //Similiar al onload o document ready


open(modLogin) {
  this.nameMod=modLogin;
  this.modalService.open(this.nameMod);
}

login(){ //Metodo

  var parametros = {
        "usuario": "PrecaNuevo",
        "clave": "PrecaNuevo",
    };

    $.ajax({ //Llamo a la funcion 
        data: parametros,
    url: this.url,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {

    }
  });
}

}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; //Importo  AppComponent
import {CabeceraComponent} from './Cabecera/cabecera.component';
import { ColaComponent } from './cola/cola.component';
import { CabeceraLineaComponent } from './cabecera-linea/cabecera-linea.component';
import { FechasComponent } from './fechas/fechas.component';
import { DatoCampoComponent } from './dato-campo/dato-campo.component';
import { CalBrixFirmComponent } from './cal-brix-firm/cal-brix-firm.component';
import { PredicfirmComponent } from './predicfirm/predicfirm.component';
import { DefectosComponent } from './defectos/defectos.component';
import { ApiLoginComponent } from './api-login/api-login.component';
import { LoadFormVComponent } from './load-form-v/load-form-v.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
    CabeceraComponent,
    ColaComponent,
    CabeceraLineaComponent,
    FechasComponent,
    DatoCampoComponent,
    CalBrixFirmComponent,
    PredicfirmComponent,
    DefectosComponent,
    ApiLoginComponent,
 LoadFormVComponent,


  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,       
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,

  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: ¿Y? ¿Qué quieres lograr? ¿Cuál es tu problema? No estás especificando nada, ¿quieres que no se ejecute en pantalla completa?

Comment: Gracias por tu interés, quiero que se ejecuta como un modal.